# I can't create a multilevel component strapi

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I was trying to make a component in strapi named link that contains:

link{
url,
newPage,
text,
link,
}
my idea was to make a link component that with a link component inside of it so i can make a multi level dropdown component in my navbar (nextjs) but strapi didn't let me to add a component as an attribute so i tried to add a relation and somehow after that it letted me adding a link component, but now when i'm trying to acces all i see y blank page, i don't know how to reverse it.
i hope i made myself clear.

i tried to delete the component but because when i try to access the editor page all i see is a blank page

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.